PySide's QUiLoader doesn't show widget
I developed a kind of complex UI in Designer and loaded it in PySide6 using QUiLoader.
It worked during development, but just when I thought I was finished, it doesn't show anything any more. The script starts and runs, it just doesn't show any windows any more.
I'm running this on Windows 11, Python 3.12/PySide 6.7.2, and 3.11 with PySide.
I'll give you a stripped-down version with the same behaviour, I really hope you can help me with this:
(the path to HelloWorld.ui is correct; I dbl checked it several times.)
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from PySide6.QtCore import QFile
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        loader = QUiLoader()
        ui_file = QFile('D:/Path/to/HelloWorld.ui')
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        self.window = loader.load(ui_file, self)
        root_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        root_layout.addWidget(self.window)
        self.setLayout(root_layout)
        ui_file.close()
app = QApplication.instance()
if not app:
    app = QApplication()
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec()


Did you run the script in a command prompt to check for possible debug output the IDE may not show? Does creating a plain QWidget (no subclasses involved) and showing it work? Maybe consider uninstalling and reinstalling PySide again.

I don't use an IDE, instead I use Visual Code and it's build in Terminal. I also tried Windows Terminal. Can you give me an example how creating a plain QWidget with QUiLoader works? I'm not sure if I know what you mean by that.

Just replace window = Window() with window = QWidget().
